# Terminal can't access paths under users (Win10)

Tags: windows-10, command-line, path

In Windows 10 I've named my home directory after my first and last name, however, whenever I try to reference a file location in the terminal, it cuts off the path into two paths, here's an example:

```
C:\Users\My Name\Pictures\abc.png
```

It returns something like:

```
directory 'C:\Users\My' could not be found
```

I'm curious if there is some kind of formatting that could resolve this issue.

Comment: Unsure, but I think Windows will accept %20 instead of a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blank is taken as a separator.

To use in the Command Prompt a folder or file name containing blanks,
you need to enclose it in quotes, like this:

```
"C:\Users\My Name\Pictures\abc.png"
```